# Following JavaScript ternary operator code not working correctly

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

```js
let a = prompt('Enter 1st number');
console.log(a);
let b = prompt('Enter 2nd number');
console.log(b);
let msg = (a + b < 4)?'Below':'Over';
console.log(msg);
```

Following code Outputs :

Case 1 : a=0, b=1, msg='Below'
Case 2 : a=1, b=1, msg='Over'

Case 2 answer should be 'Below;,
Where am I wrong ?

Comment: As a shortcut you can use `let a = +prompt('Enter 1st number');` to convert the returned string to a number on the spot.

Comment: You can use as `parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)` for converting string to int

Comment: @AhmetAmasyalı I just got the answer and in my solution I am using Number() to convert them into number datatype :                                            let a = Number(prompt('Enter 1st number'));
console.log(a);
let b = Number(prompt('Enter 2nd number'));
console.log(b);
let msg = ( a + b < 4)?'Below':'Over';
alert(msg);